# java field qualifier best practice

Tags: java, spring

It is a good practice to use a proper qualifier between *private, protected, private or default*. But is there any other reason like performance or JVM optimization drawback default is used instead of private? As an example

```
public class Class1{
    Class2 class2;
}
```

And where variable class2 could have been private.

Also if the variable is autowired or injected by DI framework. Framework calls `field.setAccessible(true)`. Does that make any difference as per the performance or optimization.

Comment: a gun is not supposed to be used to kill innocent people, yet that is what it's used for most. Just because you don't intend for code to be used in a certain way, or by third parties, doesn't mean it won't be.

Comment: It would be great if the answer is based upon technical terms like performance, JVM variable thread cache, pit falls in terms of testability etc

Comment: Of course it is good practice to do that!  It sounds to me like you are fishing for an excuse to not fix some code with sloppily / incorrectly chosen access modifiers.  Sorry.  No dice.  Fix'em ... like your code reviewer said!

Comment: In my experience, you can never go wrong by exposing as few members and methods as conceivably possible.

Comment: i am looking for a good reason to force someone to follow the practice. :)

Comment: @PrasenjitPurohit You have a reason to have them follow the practice.  Ask them for a reason not to.

Comment: They said spring anyway makes the field accessible by reflection at runtime, then whats the point in making it inaccessible.

Comment: @PrasenjitPurohit unless you understand the basics, going to look for 'technical terms like ...' is a bad idea. here's one big ass pitfall: your variables will be able to be used in a way you can't foresee.

Comment: @PrasenjitPurohit The compiler won't let you access the field.  It will be made accessible at *runtime* not compile time, meaning nowhere in your program can you access something that shouldn't be accessed, unless say, you used reflection yourself to access it (which is a bad idea in general).

Comment: The way to force people to write decent code is to get your project manager / quality manager to adopt a coding standard ... and insist that it is followed. (But this can be easier said than done if your management doesn't understand the long-term costs of poor quality.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I now understand the motivation for this question.

The reasons for using the correct access modifiers on variables in normal Java are well understood.  Basically, it is all about modularity, encapsulation, avoiding unwanted / harmful coupling and so on.

What about Spring?

Well it is true that Spring can circumvent normal access rules and allow you to inject `private` variables.  However, from what I understand, you have to deliberately annotate your private fields with `@autowire` or similar for this to occur.  What is actually going on here is that Spring is following an "instruction" that is *explicitly declared in the source code* by means of the annotation. Spring XML-based wiring won't let you inject a value into a private field or using a private setter.

In the light of this, the argument that Spring allows you break private encapsulation is ... while technically true ... ultimately self-serving.  Sure, you can do it.  But you have to do it *explicitly*, deliberately ... by design.  And it ONLY happens when the objects are wired.

By contrast, if you are sloppy about the modifiers, and declare every instance variable as `public` or package private, then you are leaving open the possibility of all sorts of lazy, ill-considered, or even accidental breaking of encapsulation.  And even if you (the original author) are disciplined, the next guy reading / maintaining your code can't be sure that you *have been* disciplined.  He has to *check* ...

So how do you "force" someone to toe the line?

It is probably best to persuade rather than force, but the way to force people to write decent code is to get your project manager / quality manager to adopt a coding standard, and insist that it is followed. (But this can be easier said than done if your management doesn't understand the long-term costs of poor quality.)

The real reason we have these pesky coding standards is so that the code can be maintained ... by someone other than the guy who wrote it.  A good IT manager will understand this.  A good PM will understand this.  A good programmer will understand this.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not meant to be used by any other application - then just make it private. The point is OTHER developers can't read your mind. And if it's not private, then they will think, that it is meant to be used outside of class.

Comment: This is a good point in terms of coding style and developer practice. But is there any other reason in terms of performance or something serious.

Comment: @PrasenjitPurohit That should be reason enough to not do it.  If you can pick between a filet mignon or a half-burnt hamburger patty with no bread at a restaurant and you pay the same for either, pick the filet mignon...

Comment: @PrasenjitPurohit i don't think that there is something about performance. It is serious not only in terms of coding style, but also in terms of maintaining your project. If later you will need to change this variable, and it is not private, and it is used somewhere else, then you will have a trouble.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer if there is no other reason found.